# Using Linq and C#, how could I kinda merge two lists over some criteria?

Tags: c#, linq, merge

### The context

---

```
public class Item
{
    public int Index;
    public string Text;
}

...

var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {Index=1, Text="Data #1"},
    new Item {Index=8, Text="Data #8"},
    new Item {Index=4, Text="Data #4"},
};
```

### The code

---

```
var data = (from item in items
           orderby item.Index
           select item).ToList();
```

### The result

---

> Data[0] = Data #1
>   Data[1] = Data #4
>   Data[2] = Data #8

### What is wanted

---

> Data[0] = null
>   Data[1] = Data #1
>   Data[2] = null
>   Data[3] = null
>   Data[4] = Data #4
>   Data[5] = null
>   Data[6] = null
>   Data[7] = null
>   Data[8] = Data #8

How to achieve this with Linq?

Comment: I think you may have made a typo in your question, you show Data #3 at index 4, then later show Data[4] = Data #4.  But essentially you want to have an list with all 9 values, and fill in nulls where a value is not provided?

Comment: That could be very tricky because Data #5 and Data #4 are not listed elements in your dataset..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you need is a left join between a sequence of numbers and your list of items:

```
var result =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, items.Max(it => it.Index) + 1)
     join item in items on i equals item.Index into g
     from item in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

This does what you want:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, items.Max(x => x.Index) + 1)
                       .Select(i => items.Where(x => x.Index == i)
                                         .Select(x => x.Text)
                                         .SingleOrDefault())
                       .ToList();
```

Result:

```
result[0] = null
result[1] = Data #1
result[2] = null
result[3] = null
result[4] = Data #3
result[5] = null
result[6] = null
result[7] = null
result[8] = Data #8
```

You could improve performance by storing the original data in a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.Text);
List<string> result = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < d.Keys.Max() + 1; ++i)
{
    string s;
    d.TryGetValue(i, out s);
    result.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Is it possible to use a LINQ expression instead?

Comment: Dictionary idea seems like totally the way to go, though I would think this wouldn't tihnk this would improve performance because the dictionary has to follow it's key match algorythm instead of an indexer which just goes strait to the memory space.

Comment: Performance is not a problem since the source list contains at most 20 items.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] myData = new string[items.Max(item => item.Index)];

foreach(Item myItem in items)
{
    myData[myItem.Index] = myItem.Data;
}
```

Comment: string[] myData  // myData[myItem.Index] = myItem.Text

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Ah right, duh. I knew I was doing it that way at first for a reason.. fixed, thanks.

Comment: I like this, although it turns out that the OP wanted a LINQ solution and this isn't really using LINQ. +1 anyway because it's clean and simple.

Comment: I still think this is the cleanest and the fastes one.